# Why is repaint() not calling paintcomponent in a swing timer?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint, repaint

When I use repaint() in the swing timer method startTimer, it just simply doesnt call paintcomponent(). Everything works inside of the timer method except repaint(). Im pretty new at java so if anyone could help me with this problem or point out any other errors I would greatly appreciate it. thank you

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Board extends JPanel {
    Timer timer;
    int count;
    int clockNumber;
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(30, 30, 640, 640);//makes a black square
        for(int i=30;i<=510; i+=160)//adds white columns
        {
            for(int j=30; j<=510; j+=160)
            {
                g.clearRect(i,  j,  80,  80);
            }
        }
        for(int i=110; i<=590; i+=160)//adds black columns
        {
            for(int j=110; j<=590; j+=160)
            {
                g.clearRect(i, j, 80, 80);
            }
        }
        g.setFont(new Font("Monospace", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("a", 85, 660);
        g.drawString("c", 245, 660);
        g.drawString("e", 405, 660);
        g.drawString("g", 565, 660);
        g.drawString("7", 35, 140);
        g.drawString("5", 35, 300);
        g.drawString("3", 35, 460);
        g.drawString("1", 35, 620);
        
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("b", 165, 660);
        g.drawString("d", 325, 660);
        g.drawString("f", 485, 660);
        g.drawString("h", 645, 660);
        g.drawString("8", 35, 60);
        g.drawString("6", 35, 220);
        g.drawString("4", 35, 380);
        g.drawString("2", 35, 540);
        System.out.println(clockNumber);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(clockNumber), 300, 300);
    }
    public void showX(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setFont(new Font("wrongFont", Font.BOLD, 200)); 
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("X", 35, 540);
    }
    public void boardImage()
    {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Board());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        CoordinateGame game=new CoordinateGame();
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                int x=e.getX();
                int y=e.getY();
                    
            }
        }); 
    }
    public int clockNumber()
    {
        return clockNumber;
    }
    public void startTimer(int seconds)
    {
        ActionListener action=new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                clockNumber=count;
                if(count==0)
                {
                    timer.stop();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(count);
                    clockNumber--;
                    count--;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
            
        };
        timer=new Timer(1000, action);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
        count=seconds;
    }   
}
```

Comment: (1-) The creation of the frame should NOT be part of the Board class. Your main() method should create the JFrame and add the Board component to the frame. I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial on `Custom Painting` in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67807288/131872 and stated you should use the working code as a starting point so you will have better structured code. You did not follow the tutorial and you do not have better structured code. You should NOT be adding the MouseListener to the frame. That is NOT what the tutorial does. Read the tutorial!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a runnable example I should suppose that you're doing something like

```
Board board=new Board();
board.boardImage();
board.startTimer();
```

The problem is in boardImage() that creates a new instance of Board and adds *that* instance to the JFrame, not the original `board`, on which you start the timer.

So replace

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new Board());
```

with

```
frame.getContentPane().add(this);
```

Consider also removing the explicit `setSize` on the frame and add override `getPreferredSize` on your custom component, then use `frame.pack()` to automatically adjust the frame size to the board.